# PHP crypt($pw,$salt) Blowfish equivalent for Android (Java)

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

I use Blowfish to encrypt the passwords with an randomly-generated salt, which is also stored in the DB.

```
$password = "someString";
$salt= "$2a$07$0dade6ad90a6cc2639b236876538b5fe$" // "$2a$07$". md5(mt_rand()) . "$";
$pw = crypt($password,$salt); // $2a -> Blowfish
// $pw would be $2a$07$0dade6ad90a6cc2639b23uwYL2QMyqG3piDr3N/D0oGvdD4NF7CIy
```

So and my actual problem is:
I am writing an android application which needs a login. So when I sent the data from the password field via POST without encryption this is really unsafe.

So is there a way to generate a Blowfish PW ON ANDROID? I've tried many other tutorials like 
[Encrypt And Decrypt Using Blowfish In Java](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/07/15/encrypt-and-decrypt-using-blowfish-in-java/)
[Encrypt Using Blowflish And Java](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/05/18/encrypt-using-blowflish-and-java/)
Also found this: [PHP crypt(pass, salt) alternative in Java - Blowfish algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570655/php-cryptpass-salt-alternative-in-java-blowfish-algorithm) but didn't solved my problem

That's from the first link:

```
public static String encryptBlowfish(String to_encrypt, String strkey) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(to_encrypt.getBytes()).toString()); // Added here .toString() because otherwise I get some hardcoded text
    } catch (Exception e) { return null; }
}
```

**but when I encrypt the password with the salt I got only a string with a length of 11...**
So i call `encryptBlowfish("someString","0dade6ad90a6cc2639b236876538b5fe");` and the return String is `[B@42ab9778`

**So what am I doing wrong?!**

Comment: byte arrays are not strings, Java is not php.

Comment: So how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To get your correct crypto password, use not the return new

> `return new String(cipher.doFinal(to_encrypt.getBytes()).toString());`

Instead

```
Base64.encodeToString(Data,Base64.DEFAULT); //Data is the result cointainer of cipher.doFinal.
```